# What color is "puce", and why do different people give radically different answers (purplish vs greenish)?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, differences, colors

It seems like "puce" means two different colors depending on where you live. I always thought puce was green, then saw on Wikipedia that it is purplish-brown. Further research tells me that it's generally regarded as purplish-brown in the United States, whereas Europeans think of intense shades of green when they hear the word. (The etymology relates to fleas, and the color of their blood-stained droppings.)

**So, why do people think of it it so radically differently, and wherever did the concept of green come into the word *puce*?**

---

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puce): Puce

On the difference in interpretation:

> 1. [Yahoo](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070119191802AAT8sa1): *What does the color puce look like? I never heard of it until just now.*
> 2. [Peggy Oberlin Interiors](http://www.peggyoberlininteriors.com/index.php/2011/08/puce-puse-peuse-peuce-lets-boycott-this-color/): *Puce , Puse , Peuse , Peuce – Let’s Boycott This Color!!!!*

Comment: It's interesting, because I can find a lot of people *claiming* that puce green is a colour that exists, but I can't find many usage examples - this [Google nGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=puce%2C+puce+green&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) doesn't show 'puce green' at all, and these examples from [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/puce) suggest the purple definition when not ambiguous (i.e. "he turned puce with anger" makes more sense with purple than green).

Comment: The discussion on Wikipedia verigies what you're saying under the section for "puce green": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3APuce

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything definitive regarding the origin of the green definition, but I have found a couple of fascinating articles explicitly detailing its history as purple: http://books.google.ca/books?id=UbXao0TjfKgC&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181#v=onepage&q&f=false http://cabinetmagazine.org/issues/32/sanders.php It's possible that the green notion came about due to conflation with puke green, although I admit that's speculation on my part.

Comment: @tajmo: Do you recall when and from whom you first learned puce is green?

Comment: This is why we should all use HTML color codes and forget these confusing words to describe colors. If you just said "#fe63e9", we'd know exactly what color you meant.

Comment: @Jay: Don't you mean #CC8899?

Comment: @Hugo, I've known for a long time that I was confused about my definition of puce. I assumed it was green, looked it up and found it was brown-purple, but found today people from England telling me they remember it as green. So, it's mostly just been confusing and I finally had to do some research.

Comment: @Hugo Well, the gloves in JRs post are around #966c80. (Of course there are shadings, but thereabouts.) So if they are what is considered "puce", I guess that's it. Say #996688 to put it in round numbers.

Comment: @Hannele: Your nGram search may be flawed (if I'm understanding it correctly). Isn't it the point that **puce** is a green color (according to some), as opposed to **puce green** being the name of a color?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found an interesting [**grammarian blog**](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/05/puce.html) on this very topic.  Essentially, the post avers that *puce* is dark purple, but acknowledges the false notion of a "puce green" still persists.  (It's theorized that the term might be an adaptation of *puke green*, but also readily acknowledged that there's no strong evidence to prove that notion.)

Also, I found a dress on Ebay today that was described thusly:

> *This fabulous Chetta B size 14 cocktail dress is created in a gorgeous
>   deep, rich eggplant purple with a shadow of puce green in a beautiful
>   brocade that is 100% silk*.

I suppose that would mean the dress in question is puce-on-puce?

Lastly, I typed "Puce dress" into Google's search engine, and then clicked *Shopping*; this is what showed up on my screen:

[image]

The conspicuously un-puce dress in the middle is being sold as *used*, so it might disappear from the search query results in a few days.  However, it does present some tangible evidence that some people indeed mistakenly refer to *pea soup green* as *puce green*.

As for *why* such misperceptions persist and become widespread, it only takes one exposure to misinformation to lock it into one's brain.  This reminds me of a friend who once related how, while working on a project in his garage, he playfully asked his daughter to fetch him a "sawdonkey", making what he assumed was an obviously humorous pun on the word "sawhorse".  Problem was, his young daughter didn't know what that object was called, so she simply noted the reference, and tucked it into her brain.  Several years later, she was working on a stage crew in college, and it took five or six people to convince her that the object in question was indeed called a *sawhorse*, not a *sawdonkey* – she even called her dad that night to verify.

Comment: I love the sawdonkey story. And it turns out somebody agreed with the definition: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbwsFKCUZpA.

Comment: That reminds me of how a lot of folks think *droll* means stupid instead of funny, or that *Nimrod* means dolt instead of mighty hunter. Both are from misunderstandings of children’s cartoons.

Comment: My dad always used lots of those ‘obvious puns’, and it's caused me to unknowingly have quite a few interesting variations as the default forms of words and idioms. I was at least a teenager before I realised that the word is _idyllic_ and not (as I'd always blindly copied my dad) _idylleric_.

Answer (score 14):

I always thought puce is purplish, perhaps because the Welsh word piws (pronounced "puce") means purple.

The word entered English from the French, where it had become a fashionable colour amongst the French aristocracy. The earliest OED citation in French is 1775, and in English is 1781 for the noun and 1787 for the adjective, but I found an earlier English example.

In the [1779](http://books.google.com/books?id=atU0AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22but%20the%20colour%20de%20puce%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OUC_T_XnK6an4gSMmvzDCQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA) epistolary novel *The Sylph*, published anonymously by Georgiana Cavendish, Duchess of Devonshire, the protagonist appropriately describes confusion with new and unfamiliar colour names:

> I have had a thousand patterns of silks brought me to make choice and such colours as yet never appeared in a rainbow. A very elegant man, one of Sir William's friends I thought, was introduced to me the other morning.-I was preparing to receive him as a visitor; when taking out his pocket book he begged I would do him the honour to inspect some of the most fashionable patterns, and of the newest taste. He gave me a list of their names as he laid them on the cuff of his coat. This you perhaps will think unnecessary and that, as colours affect the visual orb the same in different people, I might have been capable of distinguishing blue from red, and so on; but the case is quite otherwise; there are no such colours now.
>
> "This your ladyship will find extremely becoming - it is *la cheveaux de la Regne*; but the ***colour de puce*** is esteemed before it, and mixed with *d'Artois*, forms the most elegant assemblage in the world; the *Pont sang* is immensely rich; but to suit your ladyship's complexion, I would rather recommend the *seuile mort*, or *la noysette*".
>
> Fifty others, equally unintelligible, he ran off with the utmost facility.

---

I've no idea why some people think puce is greenish, but I did find this from an [1811](http://books.google.fi/books?id=yuIEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA189&dq=%22puce%20green%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b5m-T4-mKrPR4QS219FV&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22puce%20green%22&f=false) *The Medical and Physical Journal*:

> In general, imperial tea is deep green, **green tea is puce green,** hyson is blueish green, bohea is yellowish green, peko is almost black, gunpowder tea is greyish green, souchong is reddish.

This isn't necessarily saying puce is green; it's saying this green tea is coloured green with a hint of puce (whatever colour puce is).

---

I expect the confusion is much older, but puce has been mistaken at least in [1992](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=OqG-T_u5BJP64QScgd27CQ&id=ueVaAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22puce%20is%22%20green%20-%22puce%20is%20grave%22&q=puce#search_anchor):

> I said. "Nobody could pee that much. A beautiful color, puce." "Puce is pink, not yellow," Abdhul said.

And in [1995](http://books.google.com/books?id=_qAbAQAAMAAJ&q=%22puce%20is%22%20green%20-%22puce%20is%20grave%22&dq=%22puce%20is%22%20green%20-%22puce%20is%20grave%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OqG-T_u5BJP64QScgd27CQ&ved=0CGMQ6AEwCTgU):

> ... Most people describe it as an icky yellowish green, when it's actually a reddish brown.
>   NW: Could that be because puce sounds like puke, so we think of vomit?
>   LE: Probably. There is something more than slightly odoriferous about the way the word sounds. But there's an alternative name taken from Old English that sounds even worse: pewke.
>   NW: Whereas puce comes from the French for "flea"?
>   LE: Right. That's how to remember that puce is a reddish brown — it's the same color as an engorged flea belly.
>   NW: That's kind of up there with puke. "Oh, I love this dress! It's the color of an engorged flea belly."
>   LE: Not a pretty picture, is it? We'd swear Wuthering Heights is one ...

And possibly in [1988](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.smalltalk/browse_thread/thread/5451283d33d4f4d/7c582684322d54ab?q=puce%20colour#7c582684322d54ab):

> Also, one needs some code to run at the outset that insures the color table 
>      is the way you like it when you start up Smalltalk, or after you've done 
>      something else, your pretty sky blue Browser label may have turned a sickly 
>      puce!

The only explanations I've found involve mistaking puce for a puke green.

Comment: "_Fifty others, equally unintelligible, he ran off with the utmost facility_." This is a great answer, yet I found myself very, very curious about the names of those other 50 colors. Maybe that says sad things about me.

Answer (score 6):

The Macmillan Dictionary offers both American and British editions, both of which agree on the definition of [*puce*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/puce):

> something that is puce has a color between dark brown or dark red and
>   purple

I particularly enjoy Merriam-Webster's definition of puce:

> **puce**, *n*. : a dark red that is yellower and less strong than cranberry, paler and slightly yellower than average garnet, bluer,
>   less strong, and slightly lighter than pomegranate, and bluer and
>   paler than average wine

Dictionary.com quotes this etymology for [*puce*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/puce?s=t):

> 1787, from Fr. puce "flea," from L. pucilem (nom. pulex) "flea,"
>   cognate with Skt. plusih, Gk. psylla, O.C.S. blucha, Lith. blusa, Arm.
>   lu "flea." It is the color of a flea.

I don't see the color green referenced in any of the preceding sources.

EDIT: Here's Pantone's color swatch for [puce](http://www.pantone.com/pages/pantone/colorfinder.aspx?c_id=4403).

EDIT II: To answer the question, people may associate puce with green because they confuse "puce" with "puke." [This article](http://blog.catherinedelors.com/marie-antoinette-and-the-color-puce/), which asserts that Louis XVI coined "puce" to describe the color of one of Marie-Antoinette's dresses (which, truth be told, is a sort of pukey green) may lend credence to this theory.

Comment: The questions asks: if these are the definitions, then why do so many people think it's green?

Comment: @Hugo Because 'common knowledge' isn't necessarily true?

Comment: @Hugo You get the same problem with words like *chartreuse*, *taupe*, *mauve*.  I’ve absolutely seen people think those respectively mean red, blue, and green.  Do they?  Of course not.

Comment: @tchrist, the crayola multi-pack labeled an orange crayon with "chartreuse" for years.

Comment: @tajmo And what might you conclude from that? I conclude they don’t know what the word *chartreuse* means. This happens all the time. It’s an example of catachresis in action.

Comment: It seems I am mistaken about Crayola. It was a fluorescent yellow they called chartreuse. Not wrong, but not right. If enough people have the wrong definition, when does it become an alternate meaning?

Comment: @tajmo: That's not very helpful of a colour manufacturing company! In 1990 Crayola renamed [Chartreuse to Atomic Tangerine](http://www.georgehernandez.com/h/xzMisc/Color/CrayolaColors.asp) #FF9966. Here's a [Tangerine Atomique](http://southfloridadaily.com/2009/03/03/crayola-sunset/) below something more chartreuse.

Comment: @tajmo: Hmm, but then [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Crayola_crayon_colors) says Laser Lemon #FEFE22 was renamed from renamed from "Chartreuse" in 1990, and Atomic Tangerine #FFA474 was renamed from Renamed from "Ultra Yellow" in 1990. [Crayola.com](http://www.crayola.com/explore-colors/chartreuse.aspx) also shows Chartreuse matching Laser Lemon and looking more like a yellow chartreuse should.

Comment: @Hugo Here's [Pantone Chartreuse](http://www.pantone.com/pages/pantone/colorfinder.aspx). (I think I have a shirt this color...) Pantone _is_ in the business of color; Crayola just makes crayons.

Comment: @hugo The atomic tangerine matches my fallible memory best. How could two articles on the Internet have conflicting information? LOL

Comment: @tajmo: It's of course possible that they had different colours with different labels in different markets or at different times!

Comment: There is some serious win in that Merriam-Webster definition.

Answer (score -2):

Oxford English Dictionary

> puce: A dark purple brown or brownish purple colour.

**added**

My answer:  It has nothing to do with where you live.  Thinking *puce* is a greenish color is always an error.

Comment: The question is why is it thought of differently in different parts of the world? And more importantly, where did the "green" come from?

Comment: So far seen no real evidence for the green.  But then, I live in the US... One would think if the green definition were used in England, that OED would have included that.

Comment: If you look a the biological literature, you'll notice that the food sources of the fleas in Europe (including the British Isles) result in excrement colored purple/brown, whereas in North America, they result in the dark green color. The physiology of the fleas from the two continents is the same of course.

Comment: @Mitch: Maybe this is TMI, but the same thing happens to me sometimes...

Comment: @GEdgar, you would think, hence the question.

Comment: @Mitch: Interesting, do you have any references?

Comment: @tajmo It is not different in different parts of the world. Green not purple is a catachrestic use unattested by the OED. The 2007 OED3 further writes: “< French *puce* (noun) dark purple brown or brownish purple colour (1775), transferred use of *puce* flea (c1170 in Old French as *pulce*; <classical Latin *pūlic-,pūlex* flea: see **pulicine** adj.), the colour resembling that of a flea.” Last citation is “2005 *Cosmopolitan* Aug. 88/2 — Vibrators have been known to actually fly across the departure-lounge floor,‥only to be picked up by staff and returned to the puce-coloured proprietor.”

Comment: @tchrist, it's sounding more like that is the case. Should that go in as an answer? Or should I change the question? I'm still curious to know why green is where people mistakenly go.